# Seeing Form Datalayer Info when URL Changes

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a form that when submitted, the user is taken to another page.  I cannot see the data layer info for this form in the debugger because it appears then is erased so quick when the page redirects/refreshes.  Is there a way to see this info another way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do that, depending on your form:

1. You can try `CTRL` + `Click` or `Shift` + `Click` to submit the form via a new tab or window. That way you retain your original window with the GTM preview and can see the `dataLayer`.
2. You can add `console.log(dataLayer)` to your form submission and set your developer tools to retain the console log. This gives you another way to inspect the dataLayer.

Hope this helps.